# Seeking a cluster centre that is a point in my cluster

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I'm currently doing some clustering analysis of 3D coordinate points using the python package sklearn.cluster.

I've used K-mean clustering, which outputs a cluster centre that is calculated. What I really want is what data point of that cluster has the minimum distance to all other data points in that cluster. I'm guessing this would be the point closest to the cluster centre in my set of data, but as my data set is huge, it isn't really practical to use some sort of minimising search algorithm. Any suggestions of other clustering methods or other python scripts that could help me find this?

Answer (score 1):

Finding the closest pair to the center is only O(n), so as cheap as one more iteration of k-means -- not too bad.

It is *worse* than the mean, but your best guess.

Beware: it has **not the smallest average distance** (Euclidean).

The mean is a least-squares optimum, it has the **least squared deviation** (i.e. squared Euclidean).

This is the difference between the mean and the median. The *median* is the most central data point; not the mean. But finding the median is much more expensive than computing the average.

It should be not too hard to prove that the point closest to the mean will have the least-squared deviation of all your data points (try showing that a point that has a smaller RMSD must be closer).